# connect router via wifi to another router to extend network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a wifi router/modem combo unit (named router1) plugged into the cable outlet of my apartment. However that outlet is far away from all the things I want to plug in via ethernet. I have another wifi router (router2) and was wondering if I can have router 2 connect to router 1's wifi network an then use router 2's wired connections to connect other electronics.

Essentially computers connected either via the wifi network on router 1 or the wired connection of router 2 should all be able to see each other. I do not need router 2 to extend the wifi range so it's wifi adapter can be completely used for the purpose of being connected to router 1 if that makes any sense.

And no a wired connection between router 1 and 2 is not possible, hence the question to connect via wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a wireless bridge, this is possible, but support for it depends on your router's capabilities.

If your router does not have this capability it may be possible to change to a firmware that does have it, such as dd-wrt or openwrt.