# connecting a router to another via wifi: what feature does the router need to have?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I have the following setup (sorry for the poor diagram):

[image: a diagram showing my network setup. See below for a textual description.]

I'm currently using a TP-Link Wireless N Router WR841N in "Hotspot Router" mode to connect via WIFI to my VDSL router, which in turn connects to the internet. I connect my devices to that TP-Link router via LAN cable.

This worked for quite a while, but recently my speeds in the internal network have dropped to ~12mb/s, so I'm looking to replace the TP-Link.

I'm not sure what exact terminology to look for though. I've found the Netgear Nighthawk D7000 for a good price, but it's a VDSL router and I'm not sure it can do what I need. An alternative would be the Nighthawk RAX10, which is just a router (no VDSL), but it's more expensive and I'm also not sure if it does what I need (for reasons that aren't important to the question, I'm mostly interested in a Nighthawk).

I'm not looking to create a [wireless bridge](https://superuser.com/questions/808400/connect-router-via-wifi-to-another-router-to-extend-network). The devices on the router should be in their own sub-network distinct from the VDSL router network. I've tried searching for "Hotspot Router" (which is what TP calls the mode I'm using), but the results were not helpful.

What features do I need to look out for when buying a new router, so that it can do what I need?

Comment: I'm not sure what modern routers call it, but for what it's worth, the underlying functionality is exactly the same as what's used for "wireless bridge"... just *minus* the bridging.

Comment: @u1686_grawity yes, that does seem to be it. I'm a bit surprised there's no real name for it, since it seems like it's not *that* unusual a setup. Without a proper term to search for, it's really difficult to find a device which does what I want.

Comment: @u1686_grawity probably a stupid question, but I'm not so much into hardware/networks: If I'm mostly worried about the speed inside the network currently provided by the TP-Link (communication between the three devices at the bottom in the diagram), could I just add a (fast) switch behind the TP-Link and connect the devices to that?

Comment: There are pretty affordable "mesh" WiFi solutions that can do this. Just buy a two-pack, connect one to the VDSL router (in Access Point mode) and the other to your clients. You might also need to connect a small switch to the second AP, to get the amount of Ethernet ports you need.

Comment: @tim Any thoughts on my answer?

Comment: @Albin sorry, I got a bit overwhelmed and shelved the whole idea of replacing the router after buying one that didn't work. But thanks for your answer! When I search for WISP (router), I'm mostly finding either travel-sized solutions (where I imagine the wireless is rather weak) or stuff for ISPs. But it does give me one more keyword to search for. That plus "hotspot router", and maybe bridge/mesh gives me something to start. Thanks!

Comment: @tim yes, that's because WISP stands for "wireless internet service provider". Try "WISP router" or "best WISP router" or s.th. similar. If the WiFi strength is something you consider, do you have access to the router/AP you are trying to connect to? If so I would argue that WISP is not your best choice. Depending on the kind of access and the router/APs capabilities s.th. like a WLAN Bridge will be the better option with a  (regular) router connected to the bridge. WISP either requires a good WLAN signal (consumer devices) or creates a (good) WLAN signal (ISP devices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a router that is [WISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Internet_service_provider) capable so it doesn't only have an Ethernet WAN interface but you can also set it up by connecting to a WLAN AP (usually from your ISP, in your case the VDLS Router).

If it is not WISP capable, you will not be able to connect it to a Wi-Fi (to an AP), in this case, the router will only be able to "create" a Wi-Fi (function as an AP).

**Edit:**
in regards to you only finding portable routers and ISP devices:
WISP stands for "wireless internet service provider". If you search for a device try "WISP router" or "best WISP router" or s.th. similar. If the WiFi strength is something you consider: do you have access to the router/AP you are trying to connect to? If so I would argue that WISP is not your best choice. Depending on the kind of access and the router/APs capabilities s.th. like a WLAN Bridge will be the better option with a (regular) router connected to the bridge. WISP either requires a good WLAN signal (consumer devices) or creates a (good) WLAN signal (ISP devices).

Comment: I do have full access to the router I want to connect to. Connecting a router to a WIFI bridge (and then that bridge to the router which has internet access) seems like a decent solution, though I would have preferred one which just requires one device. Thanks for the answer & the update!

Comment: @tim Just check if the VDSL router has a LAN port (which is usually the case), if so the WiFI bridge shouldn't be a problem. I'm sure you can find a device that does both (some Asus devices looked promising, or openWRT), but I guess it's a niche requirement combination, that's why there aren't many solutions. As with most consumer all-in-one devices, it does everything but nothing really good, I guess that is why most opt for the two-device solution.